# Standard vector's and boost vector's push_back: which is faster?

Tags: c++, boost, stdvector

How the performance of boost::container::vector compares to that of std::vector, and which factors have significant influence on it?

In particular, I have heard that std::vector push_back is slower compared to vector[]. How does this compare in boost?

Comment: What are the benchmark results on your intended usage?

Comment: *I have heard that std::vector push_back is slower compared to vector[]* those two things don't do the same thing at all it makes no sense to compare how fast they are.

Comment: std::vector might be slower in debug builds (especially when using microsoft (dinkumware)). In release builds, there should be no difference.

Answer (score 1):

vector is a simple concept.  There are many std implementations, a boost implementation, a MFC implementation, and a hundred thousand other implementations.  And they should all be pretty close to the same speed in the abstract.

In all of them, it makes little sense to compare `push_back` to `operator[]` since they do 100% different things.  One checks the capacity, maybe reallocates/moves, creates a new element on the back.  The other one simply accesses an element that already exists.  However, since `operator[]` doesn't actually *do* anything, it will always be faster.